# htaccess - PHP - Hide media folder from public view

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, hide

I have to hide a media folder to where no one can see it when they view source code. For example I have this path to a file...

```
/blue/green/mediafolder/orange/purple.mp4
```

Is there any way in htaccess or php (or a hybrid of both) to simply remove the /mediafolder/ part OR rename it, while the scripts on the site still utilize it's actual location?

I've tried a lot of random htaccess tricks but nothing is quite working. Maybe it isn't possible?

Comment: .htaccess will help you hide it from Robots.  If you want to hide stuff like that from the code, you could keep the reference to it in a server side variable.

Comment: Not possible. If the file has to be accessible to the general internet, then its path WILL be visible at some point, even if only via a debugger/console/. For a SPECIFIC file, you could create a serverside alias or even symlink so that `example.com/arglebargle -> /blue/green/etc..mp4`, but then the file is STILL accessible via that alias.

Comment: interesting. I want people to access the file so that would be fine. an alias of some sort would be perfect if all they see is the alias in the html/console. I just don't want people to see the directory name/location